# Symbol.iterator in Internet Explorer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, iterator, internet-explorer-11

In an AngularJS web app, I have this block of JS code:

```
var _loop = function _loop(file) {
  // For each file a reader (to read the base64 URL)
  // and a promise (to track and merge results and errors)
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
      var type = void 0;
      var name = file.name;

      // Try to find the MIME type of the file.
      var match = mimeTypeMatcher.exec(file.type);
      if (match) {
        type = match[1]; // The first part in the MIME, "image" in image/png
      } else {
        type = file.type;
      }

      // If it's an image, try to find its size
      if (type === 'image') {
        var data = {
          src: reader.result,
          name: name,
          type: type,
          height: 0,
          width: 0
        };

        var image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('error', function (error) {
          reject(error);
        });
        image.addEventListener('load', function () {
          data.height = image.height;
          data.width = image.width;
          resolve(data);
        });
        image.src = data.src;
      } else if (type) {
        // Not an image, but has a type
        resolve({
          src: reader.result,
          name: name,
          type: type
        });
      } else {
        // No type found, resolve with the URL only
        resolve(reader.result);
      }
    });
    reader.addEventListener('error', function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
    reader.addEventListener('abort', function (error) {
      reject('Aborted');
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });

  promises.push(promise);
};

var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
  for (var _iterator = files[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
    var file = _step.value;

    _loop(file);
  }    } catch (err) {
  _didIteratorError = true;
  _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
  try {
    if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
      _iterator.return();
    }
  } finally {
    if (_didIteratorError) {
      throw _iteratorError;
    }
  }
}
```

and in Internet Explorer 11 in the last block:

```
  for (var _iterator = files[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
    var file = _step.value;

    _loop(file);
  }
```

I get this error:

> **the object does not support the property or the 'jscomp_symbol_iterator0' method**

I read that IE doesn't support Symbol. So, I tried to rewrite the code into:

```
for (var _iterator = files.length, _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator[_iterator++]).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
var file = _step.value;

_loop(file);
```

}

But I have this error:

> Can not read property "done" of undefined

So, I know that it is not supported by IE. But is there an alternative to write that loop in another way, supported by IE?

Comment: yeah but is there an alternative of write my code?

Comment: Well it is not mine, if it is of a component that doesn't work on IE, and I have to fix it

Comment: https://babeljs.io/ might be a solution ..?

Comment: babel-polyfill?

Comment: I tried to import the polyfill with cdn https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill but IE crash

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the code, if everything works in Chrome and if you use compilation for your project, you might consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support